# MSI Wix backup all modified files before reinstall or update

Tags: wix, windows-installer

A user may change/update files after the MSI was installed due patches or custom stuff. If we start an new MSI upgrade we want to keep these files in a backup folder (maybe inside temp). So how to add an action on uninstall for each file to see if this was changed related to the original file and backup this file(s) into a specific folder.

I have no idea except from writing a custom .NET code.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where you need a custom action. Nothing built-in in the Windows Installer that copies files during uninstall.

Comment: Ok i understand. How to detect in a custom action code .NET or VB that a local file is not equal to the orignial file?